# Binary classifiers and random hits

Tags: machine-learning, classification

Let's suppose a binary classifier with an accuracy of 90%. I wonder if the classifier does not know how to classify the 20% and it is hitting half of them by chance or there is another explanation. Any reference?

EDIT: For this question let's suppose that what we are trying to classify has 50% of samples in each class.

Comment: 20%.. what does this number represent? Do you mean remaining 10%?

Comment: If the classifier does not know how to classify the 20% of the samples it will hit 10% by chance and it will fail the other 10%. The 10% of failures is the error of the classifier. The other 90% is formed by  the 10% of samples successful by chance and the remaining 80%.